# How to ScrollTo next & next & next....... element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, scrollto

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="layer">
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<span class="next" style="cursor:pointer;"> (next div) </span>
```

jQuery with ScrollTo Plugin (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $(".wrap").scrollTo( $('.post').next(), 800, {margin:true} );
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/8/

It doesnt work :(
It work only 1st time

Comment: Because you always re-obtain a handle to the DOM elements with `$('.post')`, rather than re-using the object and calling `.next()` on it iteratively.

Comment: How can i fix it ? Plsss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working on Tomalak's answer you need to update the reference obj points to to the next element

http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/7/

```
var next;
$('.next').click(function() {
   if ( next === undefined ) {
     next = $('.post').next();
   } else {
      next = next.next();   
   }
   $(".wrap").scrollTo(next , 800, {margin:true} );
});
```

I've updated it with Prev but it can be improved to remove the duplication

http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/10/

I've noticed there is an occompanying plugin called [Serial Scroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html)

Final edit

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/UaGjs/13/

Comment: Alright well Prev will need to be the previous of next and not the starting point... so you'll need to check if next is undefined too.  I think we might be able to tidy that up a bit.

Comment: I just mean there is a lot of duplicated code.  Unfortunately lunch break is over here :) I've updated my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: One more thing.... Any way to hide ARROWs when :first-child or :last-child is left0 or right0 ?

Comment: @l2aelba Are you able to include Id's with these post divs?

Comment: One more thing a little thing... 4 DIVs will show but arrow-next will not hide ( i must click more 3-4 clicks that will arrow hide)

Comment: Done , with 

if (position === posts.length - 4) {
            next.hide();
        }

Comment: Yeah I think that is a sizing issue with the css.  I'm not really sure how to fix that.  Maybe play around with the widths.

Comment: Anyway to run same HTML codes as multiple sliders ?
http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/16/

Comment: @l2aelba I'm sure it is possible but I don't have much time to help out at the moment.

Comment: Its ok now, i finished about this :D

Answer (score 1):

Because you always re-obtain a handle to the DOM elements with `$('.post')`, rather than re-using the object and calling `.next()` on it iteratively.

Try the following. It's untested and rough/ready, but should demonstrate how you can get around the scoping issue.

```
$(function() {
    var $obj = $('post');
    $('.next').click(function() {
        $('.wrap').scrollTo($obj.next(), 800, { margin:true });
    });
});
```

Comment: @l2aelba: It's a starting point. Some effort is required to mould it into a full solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you always re-obtain a handle to the DOM elements with `$('.post')`, rather than re-using the object and calling `.next()` on it iteratively.

Try the following. It's untested and rough/ready, but should demonstrate how you can get around the scoping issue.

Comment: add this $(function() {
    var $obj = $('post');
    $('.next').click(function() {
        $('.wrap').scrollTo($obj.next(), 800, { margin:true });
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much luck working with next(). What I did was load all my elements of the same class into an array:

```
 myArray = $('.post');
```

Then initialize an index:

```
 index = 1;
```

Then iterate through the array:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
 $(".wrap").scrollTo( myArray[index], 800, {margin:true} );
 index++;
});
```

Hope this is helpful!